# Space between italics and blackboard bold characters with Fourier package

Tags: spacing, fourier, blackboard, italic-correction

Below is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem*{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
  Let $Q$ be a set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and \dots
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

For my taste, there's not enough space between the word "in" and the following blackboard bold R.  I thought `\/` (italic correction) would fix this, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.  So, is there another recommended way to deal with this or do the typography experts think this spacing is as it should be?

(I admit that it looks kind of OK if you zoom in, but viewed from a distance it looks wrong to me.)

Comment: For me, it's (almost) OK. What's not OK (for me), is that, in my opinion, a blackboard bold font should be reserved for… blackboard.  Personally, I type the set of real numbers as `\mathbf R` (as in Bourbaki). However, if you want to stick to `\mathbb{R}`, you can add before something like `\mkern 2mu`.

Comment: Well, my impression is that at least here in Germany the vast majority of math textbooks uses blackboard bold for the usual "special" sets (real numbers, integers, and so on).  And this is BTW also true for the two "Princeton Companion" tomes.

Comment: It's also true here in France, but for me, it's absurd: it was designed initially because it was hard to make a boldface letter with a piece of chalk.